# How to implement the Endless scroll listener for a gridview

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter, infinite-scroll

i have been trying to implement the endless scroll feature for my product listing page of a ecommmerce app. The grids show the details of the items and when i scroll to the bottom i need to show a progress bar and then append the new grid of items.

The api call works like this, I need to send a start_row_number and limit, which will send me all the items from the start_row_number to limit. Example: start_row_number = 0 and limit = 10. This will return items from 0 to 10

After that i need to load more items when the user reaches the bottom of the grid, and append it to the gridview. So i will send start_row_number = 10 and limit = 10, this will return items form 10 to 20.

As of now, i can get the items from 0 to 10 but not after that. How can i create the endless scroll feature and make everything such that it doesn't give me error such as 'too much work on the main thread'

Here is my MainActivity:

```
public class ProductListing extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.product_listing_act);
    init();
}

public void productListingApiCall(ProductListingCondtionModel productListingCondtionModel) {

    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(productListingCondtionModel.getBase_url()).setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).build();
    final ProductListingApi productListingApi =
            restAdapter.create(ProductListingApi.class);
    productListingApi.getFeed(productListingCondtionModel.getFile(),
            productListingCondtionModel.getOperation_condition(),
            productListingCondtionModel.getSearch_string_condition(),
            productListingCondtionModel.getMinprice_condition(),
            productListingCondtionModel.getMaxprice_condition(),
            productListingCondtionModel.getMincusratings_condition(),
            productListingCondtionModel.getMaxcusratings_condition(),
            productListingCondtionModel.getDiscount_condition(),
            productListingCondtionModel.getCatids_condition(),
            productListingCondtionModel.getBrands_condition(),
            productListingCondtionModel.getAffids_condition(),
            productListingCondtionModel.getStart_row_condition(),
            productListingCondtionModel.getLimit(),
            productListingCondtionModel.getOrderby_condition(),
            productListingCondtionModel.getSortby_condition(), new Callback<ProductListingPojo>() {

                @Override
                public void success(ProductListingPojo productListingPojo, Response response) {
                    final ProductListingPojo product = productListingPojo;
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            String[] t = Arrays.copyOf(product.getTitle(),
                                    product.getTitle().length);
                            int[] p = Arrays.copyOf(product.getSellingprice(),
                                    product.getSellingprice().length);
                            int[] m = Arrays.copyOf(product.getMrp(),
                                    product.getMrp().length);
                            int[] d = Arrays.copyOf(product.getDiscountpercent(),
                                    product.getDiscountpercent().length);
                            String[] i = Arrays.copyOf(product.getProductimageSmall1(),
                                    product.getProductimageSmall1().length);


                            for(int j = 0; j < t.length; j++) {
                                CategoryAllApi categoryAllApi = new CategoryAllApi();
                                categoryAllApi.setTitle(t[j]);
                                categoryAllApi.setPrice(p[j]);
                                categoryAllApi.setMrp(m[j]);
                                categoryAllApi.setDiscount(d[j]);
                                categoryAllApi.setImage(i[j]);
                                arrayList.add(categoryAllApi);
                            }



                        }
                    }).run();
                    setAdapter();
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    tv_title_header.setText(error.getMessage());
                    Log.e("error", error.getMessage());
                }
            });
}

void setAdapter() {
    adapter = new ProductListingGridAdapter(this, arrayList);
    gv_product_listing_act.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Heres the Adapter:

```
public class ProductListingGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public ProductListingGridAdapter(ProductListing productListing, ArrayList<CategoryAllApi> arrayList) {
    this.arrayList= arrayList;
    context = productListing;
    inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public class Holder
{
    ImageView im_pic;
    TextView tv_title, tv_price, tv_mrp, tv_discount;
}



@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    GridView grid = (GridView) parent;
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    grid.setColumnWidth(width);
    grid.setNumColumns(2);
    int size = grid.getRequestedColumnWidth() / 2 ;
    Double d = new Double(size * 2);
    int h = d.intValue();

    Holder holder = new Holder();
    View rowView;


    int index = grid.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    View v = grid.getChildAt(0);
    int top = (v == null) ? 0 : (v.getTop() - grid.getPaddingTop());

    grid.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);

    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_listing_gv_items_lay, null);
    rowView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(size, h));

    holder.im_pic = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.im_product_listing_gv_items_lay_pic);
    holder.tv_title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_product_listing_gv_items_lay_title);
    holder.tv_price = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_product_listing_gv_items_lay_price);
    holder.tv_mrp = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_product_listing_gv_items_lay_mrp);
    holder.tv_discount = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_product_listing_gv_items_lay_discount);

    holder.tv_title.setTypeface(EasyFonts.robotoMedium(rowView.getContext()));
    holder.tv_price.setTypeface(EasyFonts.robotoBlack(rowView.getContext()));
    holder.tv_mrp.setTypeface(EasyFonts.robotoLight(rowView.getContext()));
    holder.tv_mrp.setPaintFlags(holder.tv_mrp.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
    holder.tv_discount.setTypeface(EasyFonts.robotoLight(rowView.getContext()));

    categoryAllApi = arrayList.get(position);
    Ion.with(holder.im_pic).load(categoryAllApi.getImage());
    holder.tv_title.setText(categoryAllApi.getTitle());
    holder.tv_price.setText("Rs. " + categoryAllApi.getPrice());
    holder.tv_mrp.setText("Rs. " + categoryAllApi.getMrp());
    holder.tv_discount.setText("" + categoryAllApi.getDiscount() + "%");

    rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ProductDetails.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("operation", "");
            bundle.putString("productkey", "");
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    return rowView;
}

}
```

Heres the CategoryApiCall.java:

```
public class CategoryAllApi {

private String title, image;
private int price, mrp, discount;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public int getMrp() {
    return mrp;
}

public void setMrp(int mrp) {
    this.mrp = mrp;
}

public int getDiscount() {
    return discount;
}

public void setDiscount(int discount) {
    this.discount = discount;
}
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews check this once

Comment: I actually tried following that post. But for some reason, my gridview will scroll to the top after appending the new items. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: gridview.smoothScrollToPosition(int index) this is help to you.its scroll to particular position.

Comment: ok, i actually tried that too. But it seems to jerk back and forth. Couple of Question: 1. Where should i place the gridview.smoothScrollToPosition(int index) and 2. The appending or the call to the api doesn't seem to happen when i scroll, it seems to happen when the activity starts itself. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I see you have used a GridView.

RecyclerView has been introduced by Google and overcomes flaws of listview and Gridview which filled the ram with junk and made app clunky.

Use RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager. Also, research endless scroll in RecyclerView (which is pretty easy to implement).

I strongly recommend this for your app, since I have tried the same and result is outstanding. App is faster, ram becomes light, and scrolling is great. Also there are many features like the recyclerView object will offer. About time Google took care of such things and raise app quality.

Process may look like a task but in long run it will help you and the app users a lot.

Comment: Oh, i see. I have implemented the same concept in all other activities of the app. Anyway, can you tell me why is the error, skipping frames still appearing even though i have used threads. Will this error go away when i use RecyclerView?

Comment: I have a project where have used RecyclerView and also queried the next n items when user reaches the last row. https://github.com/ahujakaran24/BikeProject

Comment: to much work on the main thread means that you might be querying many items and gridview renders them in one go. RecyclerView + Volley will help you a lot. I have used volley in the above project.

Comment: ok, thanks i will check it out. Will let you know if i run into any other road blocks.